# Java Methods to rotate, increase size, and clear Box image in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a java program to draw an image of a box. I have most of my code finished. But, I'm having trouble figuring out a method to rotate the box by a specific number of degrees. I'm also trying to create a method to increase the size of the box by percentage and to clear my canvas of all images drawn.

This is the code I have thus far:
    // My Box class 
    import java.awt.Rectangle;

```
public class Box 
{
  public Box(Shapes canvasRef, int leftSide, int topLeft, int theWidth, int theHeight)
{
  left = leftSide;
  top= topLeft;
  width = theWidth;
  height = theHeight;
  canvas = canvasRef;
  theBox = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
  canvas.addToDisplayList(this);
  show = false;
}
public void draw()
{
  show = true;
  theBox = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
  canvas.boxDraw();
}
public void unDraw()
{
  show = false;
  theBox = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
  canvas.boxDraw();
}
public Rectangle getBox()
{
  return theBox;
}

public void moveTo(int newX, int newY)
{
  left = newX;
  top = newY;
  draw();
}
// This is the method that I tried but doesn't do anything
  public void turn(int degrees) 
  {
    int newAngle = angle + degrees;
    angle = newAngle % 60;
  }
  clearWorld()
  {
    // Clears the "canvas" upon which boxes are drawn
  }
 public void grow(int percentage)
  {       
   //The box grows the specified percentage, 
     about the center, i.e. increase each side of the box  
     the percentage indicated, with the center unchanged 
  }

// My Driver Program
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DisplayList
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Joe The Box");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(250, 250);
Shapes component = new Shapes();
frame.add(component);
frame.setVisible(true);
Box b1 = new Box(component, 150, 100, 30, 50);
Box b2 = new Box(component, 100, 100, 40, 60);
b1.draw();
b2.draw();
b1.turn(90);
b2.grow(100);
b1.clearWorld();
Delay.sleep(2);
b2.moveTo(10,10);
}
}

  public boolean showBox()
  {
    return show;
  }
  private int left;
  private int top;
  private int width;
  private int height;
  private int angle = 0;
  private Shapes canvas;
  private Rectangle theBox;
  private boolean show;
}
```

Can anyone please help me with the last three methods of my Box class? 
I'm really struck on what to add?
I'm open to any suggestions.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why do you modulus the angle? `angle = newAngle % 60;`

Comment: @CraigOtis Most likely that is a typo and should be `angle = newAngle % 360;`

Comment: @Code-Guru Ah, good point. I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

If you are rotating the box around (0,0) pre-multiply each coordinate,  by a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

```
x=x*Math.cos(t)-y*Math.sin(t)//result of matrix multiplication.
y=x*Math.sin(t)+y*Math.cos(t)//t is the angle
```

Alternatively, convert to polar coordinates, `r=Math.hypot(x,y)` `theta=Math.atan2(x,y)` and add an angle to theta: `theta+= rotationAngle`. Then convert back to rectangular coordinates: `x=r*Math.cos(theta)` `y=r*Math.sin(theta)`

By the way you don't need the modulus; Angles greater than 360 are also ok. Oh, and **all angles should be in radians**. If they are in degrees, first multiply by 2pi/360 to convert them to radians.

To scale the box, multiply each coordinate by a constant scaling factor.

Comment: +1 for straightfoward math. It's really the best way to spin a rectangle's coordinates. That part of the OP's question has been similarly asked/answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285936/easiest-way-to-rotate-a-rectangle

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to rotate a point around the origin, both of which are mathematically equivalent:

1. Use trigonometry to calculate the new (x, y) coordinates for the point.
2. Use linear algebra, specifically a linear transformation matrix, to represent the rotation.

I suggest that you google some keywords to learn more about either of these solutions. If you encounter specific details that you don't understand, please come back with more questions. You may also want to check out our sister site http://math.stackexchange.com where you can ask questions which are specific to the mathematics behind rotation animations.

Once you understand how to apply a rotation to a single point, you will simply need to repeat the calculations for each of the vertices of your box. This will be easiest if you encapsulate the calculations for a single point into its own method.