# How to rotate rectangle

Tags: visual-c++, activex, teechart

I have created a rectangle on canvas. I wanted to know that how can we rotate the rectangle 30 degree.

```
m_ctrlChart.GetCanvas().Rectangle(10, 50, 60, 100);
```

I am not able to find any API which will help me to rotate rectangle.
Thanks

Comment: Yeray's answer is the easiest. However, you could also draw it on the canvas using the Polygon or Polyline methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the functions to do this are internal. However, you could use a Rectangle tool that supports rotation. Ie:

```
  TChart1.Tools.Add tcRectangle
  TChart1.Tools.Items(0).asRectangle.Shape.Angle = 30
  With TChart1.Tools.Items(0).asRectangle
    .Shape.Transparency = 0
    .Shape.Color = vbRed
    .Left = 10
    .Top = 50
    .Width = 50
    .Height = 50
  End With
```

Of course you can always calculate the coordinates yourself using trigonometric functions as @selva-kumar [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29165081/509369).

Answer (score 0):

[Easiest way to rotate a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285936/easiest-way-to-rotate-a-rectangle) this one may help you else you can write a function using math.h (trignometric functions) and equation given in the post.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to draw Diamond and triangle shape in the graph. is there any way we can draw it in graph ?

Comment: You can use Rhombus as Diamond. Just change find coordinates like (0,0),(0,3),(3,0),(0,-3) and from using distance between two points formula  you can create Rhombus .

Comment: m_ctrlChart.AddSeries(scPoint);
 index = m_ctrlChart.Series(lSeries).AddXY(5, 9, "", RGB(255, 0, 255));
CSeriesPointerItems pointeritPoint = m_ctrlChart.Series(lSeries).GetAsPoint().GetPointer();
pointeritPoint.SetSizeFloat(10);
pointeritPoint.SetVisible(TRUE);
pointeritPoint.SetStyle(psCircle);
m_ctrlChart.Series(lSeries).SetColor(RGB(255, 0, 255));